# Multiple auto-generated image slideshows/sliders on each (custom) post?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, images, automation

I'm working on a site for a client, which will have a custom post type (homes). I'd like the client to be able to add new posts, which would ideally include multiple pictures, in different 'categories', for each home (i.e. initial construction, finish work, completed home). Each different category would then get its own slider on that 'post'.

I've considered using something like the [Premium Slider](http://www.premiumslider.matthewruddy.com/) plugin, which offers multiple sliders, and includes a metabox on each post, but it would definitely need to be modified to fit my requirements.

Any ideas on the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics of my approach to sliders:

1. Query arguments for selection of posts.
2. [Get The Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) (plus custom code and caching when needed) to mine for images.
3. Separate function for markup generation so it could be easily swapped.
4. Just add JavaScript slider you like. When you like/need another more just swap markup and script.

Of course this approach is better for pre-configured slider or parameters are generated by code and it doesn't need to have manual controls.